# NW.js with Vue.js how to open a link in a user's default browser?

Tags: vue.js, hyperlink, node-webkit

Basically the name of the title is the question itself but let me explain.

I have a solution for this, but I think it's not practical and wants to find a better way of doing it. For example, if I want to open one link, no problem here, but if say I have tens or hundreds of links the task becomes cumbersome. Is there a neat way to solve this?

Here is the code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
     <a @click.prevent="fireUpLink">External Link</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
/* global nw */
export default {
  methods: {
    fireUpLink: function() {
      nw.Shell.openExternal("http://example.com/");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Vue SFC, it expects a referenced variable to be defined or imported in the component, or be global. If you reference it from the global `window` object, it should work.

```js
window.nw.Shell.openExternal('http://example.com');
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Somehow I missed your answer. You mean to place it right in a template chunk like so `<a @click.prevent="window.nw.Shell.openExternal('http://example.com')">External Link</a>` ?

Comment: I meant in a method, not sure if in-template would work, if it does then go for it.